# Fortran print command: comma vs double slash

Tags: fortran

What is the difference between

```
print *, 'Hello', 'World'
```

and

```
print *, 'Hello' // 'World'
```

?

I'm sorry for this probably trivial question, but somehow I can't find an answer online.

Comment: In the first form you print the two items `'Hello'` and ,`'World'` and in the second form you print the single item `'Hello'//'World'`. The linked question covers in more depth what this means, but as you are use list-directed output you can ignore the parts there about format reversion.

Comment: A good way to get some intuition about the difference between these is to write two short hello world programs; one using the comma separated list-directed print, and the other using the concatenated print.  Compile them (e.g., using gfortran) with  `-S` to generate assembly code.  Diff the resulting files (e.g. `diff a.S b.S > hellodiff.txt`.  You will see the main difference between these two prints.  In the first version, there are 2 calls to data transfer statements for writing 5 characters.  In the second version, there is 1 call to a data transfer statement for writing 10 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fortran concatenate string operator is // so you have 1st string 'Hello' and second string 'World' you concatenate them to one string and put it as an argument for your function print.
This happens here :

```
print *, 'Hello' // 'World'
```

But in  this case :

```
print *, 'Hello', 'World'
```

You are putting 3 arguments in the print function

Comment: `print` is not a function and it doesn't take arguments.

Comment: I think is a built in function that works almost exactly like  `echo` in "php", also I m sure this answers his question in a noob-friendly way .

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't " 'Hello', 'World' " be two arguments?

Comment: You're welcome , I just counted the `*` as an argument like `Hello` and `World` .